# 404.17 Error showing after adding a Wildcard '*' Mime type (IIS 7)

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic, mime-types

I am trying to make extensionless url's (`domain.com/urlwithoutextension`) to be readable by my web server as an .html or .asp file, and all I'm getting is

```
  HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found
    The requested content appears to be script and will not
    be served by the static file handler.
```

Then below the error it says I can try this: 
    `If you want to serve this content as a static file, add an explicit MIME map.`

So I added a MIME map in IIS 7..

```
  Extension: *
  MIME Type: application/octet-stream
```

But I'm still getting this error. All I want to do is make it so `domain.com/thisurl` to be viewed as a .html file, without the .html extension. Help?

Comment: Sorry. Exact duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367920/extensionless-urls-with-mime-mapping

Comment: This link may be useful http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: @Kul-Tigin That worked. I simply changed it to `.` from `*` and it worked, so thank you. I searched long and hard and couldn't find that answer on stack overflow, but thank you I appreciate it. Not sure where to go from here..?

Comment: You're welcome. Excuse me I'm not sure understand you correctly, guess you're asking how I found the old question. I found it by searching `extensionless mime map in iis`. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I simply changed it to `.` instead of `*` for Extension in MIME Type, and it worked perfectly. Thanks to the comments.